# AWS EC2 adding volume ephemeral volume with Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have the following Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "suse12" {
  count                  = "${var.ec2_enabled}"
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.suse12.id}"
  instance_type          = "m5d.large"
  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.sshkey.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"]
  availability_zone      = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]}"

  ephemeral_block_device {
    virtual_name = "ephemeral0"
    device_name  = "/dev/sde"
  }
}
```

That creates the ec2 instance just fine...
but the ephemeral volume is not in the list of volumes, any ideas why not?

Comment: Are you sure `lsblk` doesn't show it?

Comment: @JakubKania I have not tried that... but are they not supposed to show on the list of volumes?

Comment: If by list of volumes you mean a list of EBSs in the AWS console then no, they shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ephemeral drives are not EBS and therefore don't show in the console.

To see ephemeral devices in your instance you have to ssh into the machine and use `lsblk` to show all block devices connected to instance.